# Emulating serial bus with JMS?

Tags: java, testing, serial-port, messagebroker

I'm currently working on meter-bus project and my testing environment includes [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/), hub4com, [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and mixed real & virtual devices.
Since I've collected enough data I want to move away from the serial stuff and go for a pure virtual tcp/ip testing environment.

So far I've written a small broker of my own which works fine for a small/tiny setup but I'm planning on doing a full scale test and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I thought of using JMS here but I haven't been doing much Java work the past 4 years so I don't have a clue which provider to chose or if JMS is the right choice here at all.

Some numbers I came up with simulating 9600 baud (may not be accurate):

```
Devices : 100-250
Messages: 17000+ per sec
MsgSize : max. 300 byte , avg. about 40 byte
Rtt: max. 30 msec
```

Most providers can handle the messages but I'm unaware of the time constraint. I hope someone can provide me some reference infos. Please also put into consideration that I can lower the baud rate which increases rtt and lowers msg count.
Not meeting the rtt constraint would mimic faulty wiring in my case :)

I'm open to any suggestions may it be design/implementation hints or pointing out existing projets/software that fit this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What is it you want to emulate with JMS? A serial port? I don't think that JMS is especially suited for such because it is a high level messaging framework intended to be used for message driven applications. BTW the messages must not necessarily arrive in the order they have been sent, although they usually are.

Answer (score -1):

As provider you can use ActiveMQ: http://activemq.apache.org